# Could Eragon have saved Brom?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

Eragon said that

> he had enough energy from the Eldunari that he could save Brom.

could he have?

Comment: A lot of people answer questions in the comments. Can you just please just make an answer please?

Comment: The implication in the book is that he could have, but it would have been a bad idea. Paolini is likely trying to leave the possibility open to explore in a future book.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

It says that if you try to bring someone back to life, your soul will flee.

Comment: Do you have a source to back this up?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Joey, it stated that Brom may be preserved enough to still return to life, in a similar way people can be saved with electrical shocks after being biologically dead. I don't have my book with me, but I do remember the part that says trying to resurrect someone was deadly, it was during Brom's training of Eragon.
As for my own answer to the question, I honestly think Eragon *could have* revived Brom if he went about it cleverly, I don't think it would be hinted otherwise. It gave me so much hope when he started talking about reviving him, but then Saphira shot it down. I mean it could have killed him, but still, Eragon casting a spell to sort-of lock Brom's body in time when he 'died' was not a coincidence.

Comment: When posting an answer, you should address the question itself rather than previous answers. Also, you could greatly improve this answer by editing it to add any relevant quotes from the source material.

Comment: Taking the [tour] will give you an idea of how this site differs from other general discussion forums and help you get a handle on things here.